# How to change the visibility of <div> tag using <form> tag and JavaScript for a "dummy" login?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, client-side

I have page main.html in it i have this code in the body tag:

```
   <form method="post">
   <p>Username: <input type="text" id="txt1" /></p>
   <p>Password: <input type="password" id="pwd1" /><br/></p>     
      <p>
          <input onclick ="checkAdmin()" class = "login_button" type="submit" 
          name="btn1" value="Login" />
       </p>
   </form>
```

in outer .js file:
    function checkAdmin()
    {

```
document.getElementById("private_content").style.visibility="visible";

}
```

in the css file i have:

```
 .private_content {
         visibility: hidden
  }
```

i want to change the visibility to visibility when the user click on Login button.
the problem is when i click on the login button the private part is visible for one moment and then disappear.

BTW is there a list of all the common JavaScript functions? i didn't find a good one for 
beginning with??

**EDIT- the following code worked for me:**

it looks much nicer and more convinent to use jQuery here is an example that do what i wanted to do, just with the

tag, it is the same idea.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide

```
  function onlyHeader(){
         $("div").hide();
        $("div#login").show();
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
  onlyHeader();
  $("#login_button").click(function(){
    var user = $("#username").val();
    var pass = $("#password").val();
    var ret = checkUser(user,pass);

    if (ret) {
        $("div").show();
        $("div#login").hide();
    }

    else {

        //user is not authorized 

    }


    });

});
```

---

### NOTE: You don't validate or store the a password on client side. On the server side you check for authentication, and store only the hash of the password.

Comment: Learn to love the [label element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to change the visibility to visibility when the user click on Login button.

Do that server side. If the user is logged on then don't show the form.

> the problem is when i click on the login button the private part is visible for one moment and then disappear.

This is what happens:

1. You modify the DOM so the form becomes invisible
2. The browser submits the form (since there is no `action` attribute it error recovers and uses the current URI as the `action`). There are various ways to stop the default behaviour from happening when you attach an event handler to something, but you don't use any of them.
3. The browser loads a new page, identical the old one, with the DOM reset to its initial state (with the form visible)

Once you have processed the form data (to determine if the credentials are correct and to log the user in if they are) then use the "logged in" state on the server to decide not to include the form markup in the page at all. There is no need (or benefit) to use JS here.

> BTW is there a list of all the common JavaScript functions?

See [Mozilla's developer content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference)

> I didn't find a good one for beginning with??

W3C has an [introduction to web standards](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Main_Page) that includes some JS content.

Answer (score 1):

it looks much nicer and more convinent to use jQuery here is an example that do what i wanted to do, just with the `<p>` tag, it is the same idea with `<div>`.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide

```
  function onlyHeader(){
             $("div").hide();
        $("div#login").show();
  }

$(document).ready(function(){
      onlyHeader();
      $("#login_button").click(function(){
        var user = $("#username").val();
        var pass = $("#password").val();
        var ret = checkUser(user,pass);

    if (ret) {
        $("div").show();
        $("div#login").hide();
    }

    else {

        //user is not authorized 

    }


});
```

Answer (score -1):

thats a good question and what ur asking is very common you could try this edit of ur code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
   function checkAdmin(){
    document.getElementById("private_content").style.visible="false";
    }
-->
</script>

    <div id="private_content">
     <form method="post">
       <p>Username: <input type="text" id="txt1" /></p>
       <p>Password: <input type="password" id="pwd1" /><br/></p>     
          <p>
              <input onclick ="checkAdmin()" class = "login_button" type="submit" 
              name="btn1" value="Login" />
           </p>
       </form>
    </div>
```

you need to have the area and a tag  which supports visible and not visible i used div with the id of  private_content wouldnt have been possible without that id where u want it rendered invisible on click u can do the opposite after the login check by making another function with visible=true

Comment: Depending on context, those comments are either [pointless or harmful](http://dorward.me.uk/www/comments-cdata/). There isn't a `visible` property in CSS and the `visibility` property doesn't accept the value `false`. Also, this doesn't address the problem at all.